# CSS file location Ruby

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

It appears that in Ruby on Rails all CSS files are concatenated into one big file. If I define a `p {}` in one CSS file the other pages follow suit. I have tried the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="posts" href="posts.css.scss" />
```

As well as:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="posts" href="assets/posts.css.scss" />
```

I can't seem to define one CSS file to one HTML page. I have found an option which may work by disabling the asset pipeline as it explained to me but I think this may have adverse effects.

How can I define one CSS file per HTML file?

Comment: Is this *RoR* question ? Then tag it ..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: OK I have a page called new.html.erb. in there i define the above link reference to specify the css file for this page. When I make a change to that file, lets say to the <p> settings it changes it for every web page. As if the css file is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for in a different CSS per page or action.  You can do this via:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'some_custom_layout'
end
```

If you want to have for a particular action

```
def foo
  # some logic here
  render :layout => 'some_custom_layout'
end
```

eg:

```
#app/layouts/some_custom_layout.html.haml
!!!
%html{lang: "en"}
  %head
    %meta{charset: "utf-8"}/
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", name: "viewport"}/
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "your_custom_css"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

Comment: OK I have a page called new.html.erb. in there i define the above link reference to specify the css file for this page. When I make a change to that file, lets say to the <p> settings it changes it for every web page. As if the css file is one. –

Comment: No it wont as your custom layout will just have that particular stylesheet_link_tag

Comment: Sorry I mean that's what is happening currently, I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: should the some_custom_layout be stylesheet_link_tag ?

Comment: @user3216968 updated answer with example, notice th stylesheet_link_tag is having a custom css, what you want

Comment: Thanks guys. I see the issue now regarding the layouts. Still getting my head around the ROR but currently I have only one application.html.erb layout file. So I guess this is essentially controlling the issue as it stands. great help thanks guys.